# Getting undefined error while running the test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

Hi I have this component with only @Input parameter. so got suggestions from fellow stackoverflow members need to test whether the data is rendered in the html. I have written the test case for that, but somehow when I run the test, i'm getting

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined`

ts code:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { XxxInfo } from './xxx-info';

@Component({
    selector: 'wf-xxx-info',
    templateUrl: './xxx-info.component.html'
})
export class XxxInfoComponent{

    @Input() header: XxxInfo;
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

spec code:

```
describe('xxx Information Component',()=>{
let component: XxxInfoComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<XxxInfoComponent>;
let xxxInfo: XxxInfo;
let nativeElement : HTMLElement;

beforeEach(async(()=>{
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [IonicModule],
        declarations: [xxxInfoComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(()=>{
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(xxxInfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    let aaa = new AAA();
    aaa = {
        ...
    };
    xxxInfo = new XxxInfo("abc",aaa);
    component.header = xxxInfo;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
});
it('should create',()=>{
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
it('should show job code',()=>{
    let code= nativeElement.querySelector('.details').innerHTML;
    expect(code).toEqual('TEST');
});
```

});

What am i missing here? any leads would be helpful thanks.

Comment: `nativeElement` doesn't have anything in it. It is `undefined`, so that's why you cannot read `querySelector` property on it.

Comment: Usually `nativeElement` is used on a component in unit testing. https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/components/

Comment: Ok, So how to test whether the input data is rendered in the html?

Comment: only one test case is enough for this component? like `expect(component).toBeTruthy();`? since my code has been 100% covered in jenkins.

Comment: If your `.ts` and `.html` file doesn't do anything with `header` variable. Then test is not required for it.

Comment: my .ts file doesn't do anything, and html file renders the input parameter. nothing else.